# Setting width constraint to Activity Indicator breaks stackviews?

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

This is what the view looks like after setting a horizontal stackview between the label and the activity indicator:

[image]

This is not the expected output because I want the label and the activity indicator to be close to each other. It looks like the stackview tried to assign similar widths to both subviews.

I tried assigning a 10 width constraint to the activity indicator and it ended up like this:

[image]

Here's the left panel:

[image]

How do I have a label with an activity indicator to the right of it?

I'm expecting something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of left panel where all the constraints and View hierarchy is visible

Comment: Added the sidebar.

Comment: Can you share the UI you are expecting

Comment: Added the expected UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because Stack View inserts constraints with required (1000) priority.
What you can do is change `Content Compression Resistance Priority` of your label and `Content Hugging Priority` of activity indicator to `1000` (no need in additional width constraint in that case)
[image]
[image]